# Isomorphic Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm solving my combinatorics home assignment and got stuck at one of the problems(number 11). [image: Click here]I can feel the statement is true intuitively, but I'm trying to prove it more formally. So please help me.

Comment: The question is upside-down.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Well, the vertices in the cycle in $G_1$ are mapped to vertices in $G_2$ with the same connectivity, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition is, like you said, clear -- they're isomorphic, so they have the same structure.

To make it more formal: you're assuming that there's a cycle of length $k$ in $G_1$.  Let's say that it is $v_1,\ldots,v_k,v_1$, where $v_1,\ldots,v_k\in V(G_1)$.  If your isomorphism is $\phi:G_1\to G_2$, how could you explicitly write out the cycle of length $k$ in $G_2$?